# Updating Mysql Row with array in php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, ajax, foreach

My cookie is like;

```
    Array
(
    [1] => 1
    [12] => 1
)
```

My form inputs like;
(adet = quantity, idler = ids in english)

```
<?php $postvalue = $_COOKIE['sepet'];
foreach($postvalue as $id =>$adet)
{
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="idler[]" value="'. $id. '">';
     echo '<input type="hidden" name="adet[]" value="'. $adet. '">';

} ?>
```

And there is my php file;

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$adet = $_POST['adet'];
$idler = $_POST['idler'];

$sql = "UPDATE student SET urun_stok=:stok WHERE urun_id=:idler";
$query = $db->prepare($sql);
foreach( $idler as $key => $n ){

    $query->bindparam(':idler', $idler[$key]);
    $query->bindparam(':adet', $adet[$key]);
    $query->execute();
}
```

}

modal js;

```
Modal Confirm
*/
$(document).on('click', '.modal-confirm', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.magnificPopup.close();

 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ge.php",
    cache:false,
    data: $('#modalAnim').serialize(),

});


    new PNotify({
        title: 'Success!',
        text: 'Satış Başarılı.',
        type: 'success'
    });
});
```

Im kinda new to php so im trying to update my db row by id on urun_stok row.
So im guessing im doing it wrong :)

Comment: Adet and stok are different words

Comment: i have added modal js aswell maybe the prob is releated with js.

Answer (score 1):

In query binding a parameter check the column names, change like below

```
foreach( $idler as $key => $n ){
    $sql = "UPDATE table SET urun_stok=:adet WHERE urun_id=:idler";
    $query = $con->prepare($sql);
    $query->bindparam(':idler', $idler[$key]);
    $query->bindparam(':adet', $adet[$key]);
    $query->execute();
}
```

Comment: actually this was my last save i accidently send old version ^^ this must be correct but somehow i am not be able to insert to db. I have changed with single insert code it worked but i dont know why i cant in foreach loop ..

Comment: oh okay! put the sql query inside `foreach` loop, means both $sql and $query variable inside loop

Comment: nop not workin :( well maybe its about the form foreach is the prob?

Comment: what is the output that you get from `$adet = $_POST['adet'];` and 
`$idler = $_POST['idler'];` variables, is it a array value?

Comment: Array ( [0] => 1 ) and Array ( [0] => 2 ) so the problem is here :) but how can i fix and also sql codes doesnt work somehow i have tryed without variables but codes doesnt work seems like we have multiple s.o.s situation here :D

Comment: omg found it changed from "foreach( $idler" to "foreach($idler" ... ok so one more question. how can i decrease the value $adet[$key] from current value like -1 

 $query->bindparam(':adet', -$adet[$key]);

Comment: I don't know what you are expecting now, on my understanding I guess you need something like this `bindparam(':adet', ($adet[$key] - 1));` what do you want to decrease the key value or ?

Comment: I want to lower this($adet[$key]) value from database row that we are updating. btw the code worked when I tryed but now its not working again :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206955/discussion-between-anitha-and-alper-aslan).